# Como lograr una curvatura con css

Tags: css

Quiero hacer un background como las siguientes imagenes, el problema es que no se como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado usar la funcion `clip-path` (en el ejemplo lo hago on una figura geometrica) pero no se si voy por buen camino.

```css
header{
        height: 100vh;
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(126,213,111,0.8), rgba(40,180,131,0.8) ); 
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 200px, 0 100%);
    }
```

```html
<header>

</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para colocar fondos con curvas es correcto usar `radial-gradient`, luego el trabajo es jugar con los ángulos y otros parámetros de la función. Aqui un par de ejemplos:

```css
body {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 45px 30px , #fff 50%, rgba(0, 255, 0, 0) 0%, #00ff00 50%);
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse farthest-corner at 45px 45px , #0f0 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, #fff 50%);
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

En cada caso debes pasar como parámetros la forma (`ellipse` ó `circle`), el tamaño (en este caso `farthest-corner`), la posición (por defecto es el centro, pero puedes establecerlo con `at valor1px valor2py`) y por ultimo los colores que quieres en tu gradiente (pueden ser en `rgba()` o color html) separados por comas y acompañados del porcentaje (de 0% a 100%).

Para mas información puedes revisar la [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/func_radial-gradient.asp).
Espero te sea de ayuda. Saludos.